# Python : Why I can't compare indexes of two dataframes when one is random sample

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a two large datasets `answer` and `truth` and I want to take a random sample from `answer` and then take the sample from `truth` that has the same index values as the sampled `answer` dataset, but it doesn't work! Here's what i do:

```python
answer = pd.read_csv("answer.csv")
a = answer.sample(700)

truth = pd.read_csv("truth.csv")
truth = truth[truth.index.isin(a.index)]

>>> print(a)
        item    question                   worker answer
9597    20308   clueweb09-enwp01-00-19667   w339    0
7371    20228   clueweb09-en0001-18-32106   w108    1
5527    20180   clueweb09-en0005-86-40955   w127    0
8505    20270   clueweb09-en0010-50-16267   w101    1
18202   20958   clueweb09-en0010-91-30990   w153    0
... ... ... ... ...
18004   20956   clueweb09-en0007-62-27063   w685    1
5532    20180   clueweb09-en0000-46-11807   w108    1
11510   20412   clueweb09-enwp00-91-09937   w353    1
6343    20202   clueweb09-en0003-34-25466   w102    0
16222   20780   clueweb09-en0011-26-41543   w683    0

>>> print(truth)
    item       question             truth
28  20002   clueweb09-en0009-15-02980   1
34  20002   clueweb09-en0010-92-14638   1
59  20002   clueweb09-en0011-89-08538   1
126 20012   clueweb09-en0007-39-22682   1
135 20012   clueweb09-en0007-24-18145   1
... ... ... ...
19610   20996   clueweb09-enwp00-98-10892   0
19626   20996   clueweb09-enwp00-97-10382   0
19663   20996   clueweb09-enwp01-53-09380   1
19676   20996   clueweb09-enwp01-63-12069   1
19688   20996   clueweb09-enwp01-69-11963   1
```

Does anyone know why `truth` gives different index values ?

Comment: Why don't you use `loc a.index`?

Comment: I also used `truth = truth.loc[truth.index.intersection(a.index)]` and still had the same problem

Comment: I would simply pass `a.index` without intersection. The statement inside the `loc` acts as the intersection. Let me try a few examples and I'll try to post an answer.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right! It works with simply `truth = truth.loc[(a.index)]`, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply pass the values within `.loc` you will however get a FutureWarning you can ignore for now. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
data_1 = {'index':[1,2,3,4,5],'Name':['Sanji','Zoro','Luffy','Nami','Chopper']}
data_2 = {'index':[1,2,5,6,7],'Enemies':['DfDqx','Kuro','BigM','Croco','Exodia']}
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_2)
df_1 = df_1.set_index('index')
df_2 = df_2.set_index('index')

df_new = df_1.loc[df_2.index].dropna(how='any')
print(df_new)
```

The match should be on index values 1, 2, and 5. Output:

```
          Name
index         
1        Sanji
2         Zoro
5      Chopper
```

I'm adding the `dropna()` because otherwise you will get returned all the values of `df_1` with `NaN` for the values were the index value doesn't exist.